# JS import statement from another folder

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn more JS and at the same time convert a older sites menu that is using jQuery for the menu.

In the current structure the menu.js file is in `js` directory relative to the index.html file.

This is an abbreviation of the current code of index.html:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function() {
    menu.init();
  });
</script>
```

What I want is to have a main.js file in the `js` directory and then use a import statement to import the menu.js file which is located in a lib directory within the `js` directory.

What I changed in the index.html file is that it now points to the main.js file instead in the `js` directory.

```
<script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

In the main.js file I tried the following:

```
import 'lib/menu.js';
```

This didn't work out, and I wonder also if its possible to have this part in the index.html file, the

```
$(function() {
    menu.init();
  });
```

done in the main.js file instead?

Comment: What are you exporting in `menu.js`?

Comment: its a jQuery file with click events for the menus ul and li items

Comment: Well it would be a JavaScript file I guess. You need to export correctly as stated in one of the below answers

Answer (score 0):

I think you need export what you want be visible inside menu.js, and import inside main.js.

menu.js

```
export { variableName1, variableName2 };
const variableName1 = 'Hey1';
const variableName2 = 'Hey2';
```

main.js

```
import { variableName1, variableName2 } from './js/menu.js';
```

Better explanation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/FfMbHbyhyppUSpKC?preview

Comment: Yes, I'll add a plunker also in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out and see if it works on my js file. But in the html file I will have reference both the js files like this: <script type="module" src="./js/lib/menu.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>

Comment: I tried out your suggestions on a plunker project: https://plnkr.co/plunk/kx0uoQ2vLLCtN5ts
But I am not still able to make the click events work out. I have changed the directory structure similar to my project

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is with the import path

```
import 'lib/menu.js';
```

This is an absolute path, and your program will be looking for a lib folder in your root directory.

You want to use a relative path. If your main.js file is in the same folder as the lib folder, the path would look like

```
import './lib/menu.js'
```

where './' represents the current folder. If you needed to go back one level, '../' will go to the parent folder, and so on.

Comment: I did actually change it to the import './lib/menu.js' but is this path in index.html file correct to the main.js file <script type="module" src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: I believe in html  src="js/main.js" is already a relative path and the './' is not necessary there, though i'm not absolutely certain.